# 8051 Family Memory Map - Stack Pointer Usage

Tags: assembly, embedded, 8051

I am looking for a good reference on the 8051 embedded processor family (specifically the 80C32) that will explain the internal memory map, and how it differs between processors in the family.

I'm currently reading how the stack pointer is initialized at reset to 07H. But I see in documentation ([here](http://www.8052.com/tutmemor.phtml#Internal%20RAM), for instance) for all processors in this family that the internal RAM, starting at address 00H, maps R7 of Bank 0 for the internal registers in the location 07H.

What am I misunderstanding about how the internal registers and the stack are mapped?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps your reset handler's first action is expected to be to set the SP to an actual useful address? Perhaps Bank 0 is the only RAM that is known to exist in all family variations at the same address, leading to that as a default so that the SP is known to point to existing memory after reset. But I am just guessing based on lots of 8-bit micro experience, almost none of which is really with the 8051 family.

Comment: I don't know about that device in particular, but as I recall indexed memory access on 8051 can't touch the SFRs and instead goes to a general-purpose RAM alias underneath, so it's reasonable to point the stack to 0x7F or higher and expect a sensible outcome.  But only on devices advertising more than 128 bytes of internal RAM.

Comment: You are right. I knew there was about this "shadowing", but forgot how that worked or how  I learned it in the first place. I was confusing the stack workings with this. The 80C32 has 256 bytes of internal RAM. The lower 128 are accessible by any memory access instruction. But the upper 128 can only be accessed by indirect addressing. MOV R0,#90h / MOV A,@R0 gets the contents of RAM at 90H. MOV A,90h reads the contents of the SRF at 90H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given in the page you linked to:

> Programming Tip: By default, the 8051 initializes the Stack Pointer
>   (SP) to 07h when the microcontroller is booted. This means that the
>   stack will start at address 08h and expand upwards. If you will be
>   using the alternate register banks (banks 1, 2 or 3) you must
>   initialize the stack pointer to an address above the highest register
>   bank you will be using, otherwise the stack will overwrite your
>   alternate register banks. Similarly, if you will be using bit
>   variables it is usually a good idea to initialize the stack pointer to
>   some value greater than 2Fh to guarantee that your bit variables are
>   protected from the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. (RBerteig, too). This makes sense. I just had an uncomfortable feeling that I was missing some info.

Comment: Ah, the stack grows up not down, and pre-increments on PUSH. So the choice of 0x07 makes sense because really simple code might only need a few bytes of stack, and might not need those registers allowing RAM to be conserved.